# Como funciona um e-commerce com barras ex: www.loja.com/meunome, e como é dividido o bd?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber se possível como funciona um grande e-commerce por exemplo, gostaria de criar meu usuário e colocar meus produtos a venda, no link exemplo:

www.loja.com.br/meunome
www.loja.com.br/seunome

Como funciona isso? A pessoa cria vários bancos de dados ou é tudo feito em uma mesma tabela? Vamos supor que tenha milhares de acessos por minuto, como funciona?

Comment: Os endereços na URL dependem muito da política da empresa que detem o sistema. Muitas vezes a política é moldada por limitações técnicas ou financeiras. Custa menos e tecnicamente é mais simples montar as URLs dessa forma.
Sobre volume de dados tal como sua estrutura, a resposta é similar. Depende da estrutura do sistema. Num único servidor pode ter 10 a 50 lojas, por exemplo, e a medida que alguma loja for crescendo em volume dados ou acessos, o lojista é alertado para fazer um upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na realidade é mais simples do que parece. Quando vc digita loja.com.br/seunome, "seunome" é um registro único, como se fosse um ID, porém mais fácil para gravar e divulgar (do que números). O desenvolvedor utiliza URL amigável pra fazer isso.
Cada produto então é vinculado a cada usuário. Na tabela dos produtos pode ter um campo chamado 'nome_usuario', então quando alguém digitar loja.com.br/algumusuario, o sistema deve retornar apenas os produtos relacionados a eles.

Já sobre os acessos, depende da capacidade do servidor. Milhares de acesso por minuto requer um bom servidor dedicado.